# Need to monitor user downloads folder for new .xlsx files, then open Excel, save the file, and close Excel

Tags: excel, windows, powershell

At work I use a tool that requires me to download a .xlsx file, open it, then save it to remove the workbook protection. I'd like to create a script that automatically opens and saves any .xlsx files that are saved in the downloads folder.

I'm assuming PowerShell is the right tool to use. I found this article that explains how to do something similar, but I need help with configuring the parameters.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/1faa97e0-2288-4bb2-b8ad-283df32779d4/can-i-open-an-excel-workbook-when-files-with-a-certain-extension-are-saved-in-a-specified-folder?forum=ITCG

What I need is for the script to monitor the $env:USERPROFILE\downloads folder for any .xlsx files. Then I need it to open that file in Excel (preferably in a minimized window), save it with the same filename, then close Excel.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the script you have written. It is likely that someone will have a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IO.FileSystemWatcher` to monitor a directory. See [Start-FileSystemWatcher](https://github.com/vrdse/PSFileToEvent/blob/master/PSFileToEvent/Public/Start-FileSystemWatcher.ps1) for an example implementation in PowerShell.